# VueJS $children is empty when using slots in the webcomponent build

Tags: vue.js, web-component

I am trying to build two custom elements with VueJS, such that they can be nested and used in any webpage or CMS such as WordPress or web app framework without npm / webpacker, etc. Think of this as building a pair of custom `<ul>` and `<li>` elements with VueJS. This is a minimal example that reproduces my issue:

I created two single-file components:

`components/MinimalInner.vue`:

```vue
<template><p>Inner</p></template>

<script>export default {}</script>
```

`components/MinimalOuter.vue`:

```vue
<template>
    <div>Outer<slot>default slot text</slot></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.$children.length, " children");
    }
}
</script>
```

And finally, this is my `App.vue`:

```vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <MinimalOuter>
      <MinimalInner></MinimalInner>
    </MinimalOuter>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MinimalInner from "./components/MinimalInner.vue";
import MinimalOuter from "./components/MinimalOuter.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    MinimalInner,
    MinimalOuter
  }
};
</script>
```

When I run this as **Vue Components** via `vue serve -o App.vue`, I get the expected output in console: `1 children` when `MinimalOuter` gets mounted.

But when I serve the below given HTML file using the webcomponent build generated via `vue-cli-service build --target wc --name fc 'components/*.vue'` , I get `0 children` instead. No errors are shown in browser console.

`minimal.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="dist/fc.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <fc-minimal-outer>
        <fc-minimal-inner></fc-minimal-inner>
    </fc-minimal-outer>
</body>
</html>
```

Somehow, `$children` is empty when using the `MinimalOuter` as a WebComponent with `<slot>`s. The docs at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-children only say that `$children` is not reactive and order is not guaranteed. I don't think `$children` array is expected to be blank when a child component has been passed via `<slot>` but I may be wrong.

**What am I trying to achieve overall:**

My use-case for accessing `$children` is building a UI for practicing flashcards and the actual code can be seen here: https://github.com/learn-awesome/flashcard/tree/master/components . Essentially, the outer component can be thought of as a carousel, and the inner components are as slides. Only the first slide is shown, but user's interaction can either push the first slide to the last position, or remove from the set altogether. So, I am hoping that `$children` will be an array of `VueComponent` instances, just like I get with `vue serve -o App.vue`, so that I can invoke `$destroy` on them. I will also need a way to invoke a method on the outer element when user clicks on a button in the inner element. Currently, I'm doing that with:

```
      if(this.$parent && this.$parent.doSomething)
        this.$parent.doSomething();
```

but I need an approach that works in both `vue serve -o App.vue` and the custom-element (`<fc-minimal-outer> and <fc-minimal-inner>` versions.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and added the Vue.use call to each component and used the --inline-vue parameter when building with the vue-cli. Now Vue2 works with the compositionapi as web component

in component script tag add:

```
import VueCompositionAPI from "@vue/composition-api";
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI)
```

vue cli call from package.json:

```
vue-cli-service build --inline-vue --name=fc --target=wc './src/components/*.vue'
```